# sending form data from angular view to spring mvc controller directly

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I have the following index.jsp view

```
<form method="post" action="/login.htm">
        First Name: <br> <input type="text" text="name" /> <br>
        Password: <br> <input type="password" text="password" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" >
    </form>
```

and the following spring mvc controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkUser(User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    System.out.println("The user logged in is "+user.getName);
    return "welcome"; 
}
```

Where the User class is an entity having the name as a property.
Is there a way so that i can send the data entered in the form directly to the spring mvc controller without passing through the angularjs controller?.
Something like the modelAttribute in the spring mvc, so that i can write the method in the controller as this

```
public String checkUser(@ModelAttribute("userLogin") User user,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {}
```

Comment: Well, that's what will happen when you submit that form. As soon as you have an action attribute in an angular form, the form is submitted "normally".

Comment: But how to get the data entered in the form?

Comment: Err, you type something in the input fields...

Comment: The user object is sent to the controller with null value.

Comment: i could see this in sysout, `user.getName`, though you are not sending `getName` from the form. did you mean `getName()`?